# Is it “I took a photo of myself” or “I took a photo of me”?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

I’ve been thinking about this for a while: if there is a photo, drawing etc. of me that I made, how would I say I created it, using this phrase:

> I took a photo of {pronoun}.

“Of” causes some weird things, so I’m very unsure of what pronoun to use.

**Would the pronoun be “me”, or would it be “myself?” Why is it that way?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "myself":

> I took a photo of **myself**.

The "of" has very little to do with it, except that "to take a photo of" expects a direct object. In English, when the object of a clause is the same as the subject, [**reflexive pronouns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun) are used:

- Me -> myself
- You -> yourself (singular), yourselves (plural)
- He -> himself
- She -> herself
- It -> itself
- Us -> ourselves
- They -> themselves

These are used when the direct object is the same as the subject.

> - He sees me. (Not reflexive)
> - I see him. (Not reflexive)
> - He sees **himself**. (Reflexive)
> - I see **myself**. (Reflexive)

These are also used when the indirect object is the same as the subject.

> - I gave **myself** a pat on the back.